# jQuery hover a link swap image

Tags: jquery, image, swap

I want to do the follow, if a user hover on a link that the image will swap with a image with '-on' at the end.

But how can i get the swap thing on the image when i hover the a tag?

**HTML code:**

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
        Here some caption
    </a>
</div>
```

*I can not place the image urls in the header...*

Comment: I have tryed the jQuery plugin 'canvasSwap' an trigger it with $('a.swap:hover img').canvasSwap(); but that didnt work... Same for some other plugins.

Comment: Have you tried using just CSS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('a img').hover( function () {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, '-on.jpg') );
    });
});
```

Read the jQuery docs on [`replace`](http://api.jquery.com/replace/) and [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: This will do the same as the CanvasSwap plugin. It only work when you hover the image it self... not when you hover the entire div!

Comment: this is a good solution too, just change the $('a img') to $('div'), and $(this) to $(this).find('a img')

Comment: This is good, but if you hover more than once it will replace imagename-on.jpg with imagename-on-on.jpg and so on. To avoid image not found add jquery out handler for hover(). Read the docs..http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 6):

To change `src` of your image just just `attr`:

```
$('img').attr("src", "image2.jpg");
```

You need to use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$("a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "image2.jpg");
},
function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "image.jpg");
}
);
```

Comment: $('a:hover img').attr("src", "-on.jpg"); when you do this you will not get image-on.jpg on a hover i think...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DOM 'mouseover' event on the a tag and attach a callback to it (then inside, you'll change the image's URL)

edit, sample code:

```
<div>
<a id="myLink" href="#">
    <img id="myImg" src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    Here some caption
</a>
</div>
```

in JS:

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
document.getElementById('myLink').onmouseover = function(){
    //manipulate the image source here.
    img.src = img.src.replace(/\.jpg/, '-on.jpg');
}
```

You will then need to use onmouseout to put the original image back.

Comment: Hi Greg, see my last line at the bottom of the topic start: I can not place the image urls in the header of the html...

Comment: note this is JS code, this does not have to be in the header of the HTML :) but I see what you mean - you cannot hardcode the URLs.

Comment: Almost! :-)... the mouseover is now good but when you leave with your cursor then the 'normal' image is not comming back? And is it possible to do it with a class?

Comment: see the end of my post: you have to do the reverse operation with onmouseout. And a CSS class cannot modify the image URL other than entirely replace it, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah you was right now it works great! Do you read the other question? Is it possible to do it with a class? So i can do it on multiple boxes?

Comment: You could use getElementsByTagName to apply the same logic to several elements with a given class, yes. It returns an array (kind of) so you would need to iterate over it with Array.prorotype.forEach to add the onmouseout handlers. Hey, remember to validate an answer :) (Dream Eater's or mine)

Answer (score 2):

```html
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('img').on('mouseover', function(){
  src = $(this).attr('src').replace('.gif', '-hover.gif');
  $(this).attr('src', src);
 })
 $('img').on('mouseout', function(){
  src = $(this).attr('src').replace('-hover.gif', '.gif');
  $(this).attr('src', src);
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Your run the code snippet feature would be pretty neat... if the code actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to have the image go back to it's original state when the mouse leaves.

```js
    $(document).ready(function($) {
     $('img').on('mouseover', function(){
      src = $(this).attr('src').replace('hover', 'thanks!');
      $(this).attr('src', src);
     })
     $('img').on('mouseout', function(){
      src = $(this).attr('src').replace('thanks!', 'hover');
      $(this).attr('src', src);
     }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/500x150/DEDEDE/555555/hover" />
```